# I want to remove everything before last space

Tags: notepad++

I have text with 10k lines like this in notepad ++

```
Last: 07/06/2006 04:00:00 mazorcanyona3:orestes88
Last: 08/18/2005 02:18:25 alexloveridge:scotty123
```

The last space is after the time. I want to remove everything before this space to get lines like this

```
mazorcanyona3:orestes88
alexloveridge:scotty123
```

Comment: does notepad++ have regex search and replace? If not then you could use `sed` (if you can use a separate tool).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation), [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html), [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: i tried many things but i cant solve it

Comment: yes there's regex search and replace but i dont know how to make it
so hard for me since lines are different and lead to massive remove not dealing with 1 line on process like removing everything before last space of last line in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+\h`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \h          # horizontal space, space or tabulation
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**
[image]

Comment: Thanks bro this worked too like a charm <3

Answer (score 0):

Search for everything after the third blank:

Find what: `^[^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]* (.+)$`
Replace with: `\1`

Where `[^ ]` stands for "not a blank", and `\1` for the first
parenthesis group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks harrymc works like charm <3